# HP DesignJet hardening / close ports

Tags: port

I am trying to close unnecesary ports at our HP designjet plotter and I still have ports 280, 8086 and 8085 open.

I have switched off everyting except raw print 9100 and these three ones are still open.

The biggest problem I am facing is that I have abosolutely no idea what are these ports for.

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

If your device itself has no way to control this, then you'll have to add additional hardware in between. For example a dual network port embedded device, maybe a smart switch supports such things, that has a bridge between the device and the network, and has a firewall that only has the used ports you have whitelisted.